# How to use SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle?

Tags: .net, multithreading, interop, unmanaged, handle

I have unmanaged code that calls an asynchronous managed method that returns a handle, and then the unmanaged code uses that handle to wait.
According to the documentation, SafeWaitHandle provides 2 other methods (`DangerousAddRef` and `DangerousRelease` ).
Should I use these methods in order to prevent the Handle from not being released? As the name of the method `DangerousGetHandle` suggest, it seems to me that I should be very careful with something, what is so dangerous here?

Edit: Is there a better way to implement this scenario (not dangerously)?

Comment: Does the unmanaged code invoke a method to indicate it's done with the handle?

Comment: yes, WaitForSingleObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the managed method returns the handle, but doesn't pass ownership of the handle to the calling unmanaged method, then you should just return the handle as a `SafeWaitHandle` directly (it will be marshalled to a handle) - this way unmanaged code doesn't have to worry about releasing the handle.
If you want to pass ownership of the handle to the unmanaged method, then you should call `DangerousAddRef` before returning the handle, but then you have to release the handle using unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousgethandle.aspx):

> Using the DangerousGetHandle method
>   can pose security risks because, if
>   the handle has been marked as invalid
>   with SetHandleAsInvalid,
>   DangerousGetHandle still returns the
>   original, potentially stale handle
>   value. The returned handle can also be
>   recycled at any point. At best, this
>   means the handle might suddenly stop
>   working. At worst, if the handle or
>   the resource that the handle
>   represents is exposed to untrusted
>   code, this can lead to a recycling
>   security attack on the reused or
>   returned handle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a better way to implement what I described?